# CFStringRef setting a value to ""

Tags: ios, ios4, nsstring, cfstring

I have a variable which is a CFStringRef and I perform a check to make sure its not 1 specific value. If it is then I want to set it to the NSString equivalent of @""

Here's the code

```
CFStringRef data = = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey);

NSComparisonResult result = [(NSString *)data compare:element options:compareOptions];
if(NSOrderedAscending == result) {
    // Do something here...
}
else if (NSOrderedSame == result) {
    // Do another thing here if they match...
    data = "";
}
else {
    // Try something else...
}
```

So in the if else block, I want to set it to "" but Xcode warns me that it is an invalid pointer type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CFStringRef is immutable object so you must create new instance with different value:

```
data = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, "", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

And remember that you need to release that value.

But since CFStringRef and NSStrings types are toll-free bridged you can just use NSString in your code (that will probably makes it easier to understand and support it later):

```
NSString *data = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey);

NSComparisonResult result = [(NSString *)data compare:element options:compareOptions];
if(NSOrderedAscending == result) {
    // Do something here...
}
else if (NSOrderedSame == result) {
    // Do another thing here if they match...
    data = @"";
}
else {
    // Try something else...
}
```

Comment: So basically CFRelease(data) then say data = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "", kCFStringEncodingUTF8)

Comment: I think CFDictionaryGetValue returns not retained string, so you should not release it in 1st case. but after you create data with CFStringCreateWithCString - you must release it afterward